# how to add array in another array's element using groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have an array of array list, I am trying to structure it using groovy but I am not getting the expected result, I have used `putALL` method to add an array but it is overriding the previous array,

I have tried this way and the output is this `[parent:health, children:[true]]`

```
        import java.util.stream.Collectors

        def fakeList = [
                        [coverageType: 'health', amount: 9, expireDate: 2020], 
                        [coverageType: 'insurance', amount: 10, expireDate: 2020], 
                        [coverageType: 'health', amount: 9, expireDate: 2021],
                    ] 

        def groupList = [:]
        def list = fakeList
                .stream()
                .map { item -> 
                        def parentWithChilds = [
                                parent: item.coverageType,
                                child: groupList.stream()
                                .map { list -> list?.parent !== item.coverageType }
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                            ]
                            groupList.putAll(parentWithChilds)
                    }.collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList())
```

My goal is if there are any same coverageType values in the array I will add them to the child list,

This is my expected output:

```
          [     parent: 'health',
                children: [
                    [
                    coverageType: 'health',
                    amount:'9',
                    expireDate: '2020'                        
                    ],
                    [
                    coverageType: 'health',
                    amount:'9',
                    expireDate: '2021'                        
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            [
                parent: 'insurance',
                children: [
                    [
                    coverageType: 'insurance',
                    amount: '9',
                    expireDate: '2020'                        
                    ]
                ]
            ],
```

Or without key:

```
  [     parent: 'health',
                    children: [
                        [
                        'health',
                        '9',
                        '2020'                        
                        ],
                        [
                        'health',
                        '9',
                        '2021'                        
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    parent: 'insurance',
                    children: [
                        [
                        'insurance',
                        '9',
                        '2020'                        
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this:

```
def fakeList = [
                [coverageType: 'health', amount: 9, expireDate: 2020], 
                [coverageType: 'insurance', amount: 10, expireDate: 2020], 
                [coverageType: 'health', amount: 9, expireDate: 2021],
            ]
```

Consider this:

```
def groupList = fakeList.groupBy { it.coverageType }
                        .collect { coverageType, items ->
        def map = [:]
        map.'parent' = coverageType 
        map.'childs' = items.collect { item ->
            def childMap = [:]
            childMap.'coverage' = coverageType
            childMap.'amount' = item.amount as String
            childMap.'expireDate' = item.expireDate as String
            childMap
        }
        map
}
```

The resulting map is:

```
[
[parent:health, childs:[[coverage:health, amount:9, expireDate:2020], [coverage:health, amount:9, expireDate:2021]]],
[parent:insurance, childs:[[coverage:insurance, amount:10, expireDate:2020]]]
]
```

Working example listed [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_groovy/tree/master/egg_stack_overflow_74515307), which also converts to JSON for pretty-printing.